# How to use Class in variable?

Tags: flutter, class-eval

I want to convert fetched data as below, but I got error and emulator shutdown!
What can I do?

```
Map<String, dynamic> responseClassMap = {
'$ResponseCompany': ResponseCompany,//ResponseCompany is class
'$ResponseCompanyDetail': ResponseCompanyDetail, //ResponseCompanyDetail is class
};
for (var item in responseClassMap.entries) {
  if (className == item.key) {
    result = responseData.map((data) => item.value.fromJson(data)).toList();
  }
}
```

Here is class ResponseCompany.dart

```
@JsonSerializable()
class ResponseCompany {
final num sales, ...;
...
factory ResponseCompany.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$ResponseCompanyFromJson(json);
...
```

Here is ResponseCompany.g.dart

```
ResponseCompany _$ResponseCompanyFromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
  return ResponseCompany(
  );
  ...
}
```

Comment: what error? please paste it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO `item.value.fromJson` will not work. Since fromJson is a factory constructor, and in dart's rule, one cannot call factory constructor for a type stored in a variable. (Indeed, the problem is hidden because you create a `Map<string, dynamic>` and dart allow everything to be called on `dynamic` at compile time.)

For your specific case, you can do

```
Map<String, dynamic> map = {
'$ResponseCompany': (d)=>ResponseCompany.fromJson(d),//ResponseCompany is class
'$ResponseCompanyDetail': (d)=>ResponseCompanyDetail.fromJson(d), //ResponseCompanyDetail is class
};
for (var item in map.entries) {
  if (className == item.key) {
    result = responseData.map((data) => item.value(data)).toList();
  }
}
```

Comment: I got error `The getter 'fromJson' isn't defined for the type 'ResponseCompany'.
Try importing the library that defines 'fromJson', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'fromJson'` when I folloeded your code...

Comment: @mikezang run code generator. I guess you are using the json lib of flutter? then read that doc first

Comment: I am sorry that I am new for flutter, can you give me more detail advice? I can use `result = responseData.map((data) => ResponseCompany.fromJson(data)).toList();` in same file, `ResponseCompany.g.dart` is no problems.

Comment: @mikezang show your *full* code, including .g.dart

Comment: @mikezang Oh I made a mistake. see my updated ans

Comment: I will test it tonight.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot!